# Covering maps and local homeorphisms

Tags: general-topology

I want to solve an exercise regarding covering maps.

> Give an example of a local homeomorphism that is not a covering map.

I tried using the function $ f:  \left]0, \frac{3}{2}\right[\to S^1, \ f(x)=e^{2\pi it}$ and looked at the point $(1,0) \in S^1$.

I wanted to prove that this is not a covering map.

Consider an open neighborhood V of (1,0). Suppose that there is a family $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ of open subsets of $\left]0, \frac{3}{2}\right[$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ can be written as the disjoint union of the sets $U_i$ and that $f \vert_{U_i}$ is a homeomorphism onto $f(U_i)$ for every $i \in I$.

I know that I somehow have to find a contradiction. Intuitively it looks like that the family of $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ consists of intervals that are contained in $\left]0, \frac{3}{2}\right[$, so I think there will be a contradiction to the statement that the sets $U_i$ are disjoint or that $f \vert_{U_i}$ is a homeomorphism onto $f(U_i)$ for every $i \in I$. But I do not see how to give a formal proof.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by the map $\pi:  \left]0, \frac{3}{2}\right[\to S^1$.  For a $t$ in the domain, which point is $\pi(t)$?

Comment: In any neighbourhood of $1$, there will be points both singly and doubly covered by $f$, so it can never be evenly covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thm: if $p: E \to B$ is a covering map and $B$ is connected, then for each $b,b' \in B$, $|f^{-1}[\{b\}|= |f^{-1}[\{b'\}]|$, so all fibres have the same size. For the $f$ at hand this is not the case: some points have a 2 point fibre, others just a fibre of a singleton. So it cannot be a covering map.